# Grabbing CSV Information with Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to extract all the phone numbers from a CSV document and append them to a list in string format.  Here is a sample of my input:

```
someone@somewhere.com,John,Doe,,,(555) 555-5555
```

And here is the code I am using:

```
l = []
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for x in reader:
        number = re.search(r'.*?@.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?,(.*?),',x)
        if number in x:
            l.append(''.join(number))
```

Basically, I'm trying to check if there is a number at a certain position in the row (where the parentheses are) and then append that to a list as a string using join.  However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/svillamil/Desktop/Final Phone.py", line 14, in <module>
    number = re.search(b'.*?@.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?,(.*?),', x)
  File "C:\Users\svillamil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: The use of regex is mandatory?

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. Also, `x` is not a string. Look at the documentation for the `csv` library.

Comment: why don't you just split a file line by comma and iterate through elements checking each if it matches (???) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) gives you a list of strings for each row.

Taking the value at index 5 already gives you the phone number (if I counted correctly). You don't need a regular expression to do this.

```
l = []
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        number = row[5]
        if number:
            l.append(number)
```

(Conversely, if you insisted on using a regular expression, you wouldn't need `csv` to do the splitting and could just iterate over the raw lines of the file.)

Comment: This worked. Thank you.  I was so focused on using regular expressions, I didn't even think to use the index numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should just split a file line by comma and iterate through elements checking each if it matches (...), assuming a phone number can appear at any delimited position in a file line:

```
import re

result = []

with open('sandbox.txt', 'r') as f:
    fileLines = f.readlines()

for fileLine in fileLines:
    fileLine = fileLine.strip()
    lineElems = fileLine.split(',')

    for lineElem in lineElems:

        pattern = re.compile("\(...\)")

        if pattern.match(lineElem):
            print("Adding %s" % lineElem)
            result.append(lineElem)
```

Comment: "Just split a file line by comma"  – that's exactly what the `csv` module is for.

Comment: i was trying to offer a more elegant alternative to "(b'.*?@.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?,(.*?),', x)", which is ugly and chaotic

Answer (score -1):

`x` is a list which contains each field of the row.

So one approach is to join the array and then apply the regex,

```
foo=','.join(x)
number = re.search(r'.*?@.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?,.*?,(.*?),', foo)
```

Or you can iterate over each field in the row and check if its a number

```
for row in reader:
   for field in row:
       number = re.search(r'<phone-number-regex>', field)
       if number in x:
           l.append(''.join(number))
```